# How to remove objects from Lists correctly?

Tags: c#, list

Hi unfortunately I do not have the according link anymore but I recently read some c# cheat sheets. One of them said that one shall not remove objects from lists while iterating with `for` or `foreach`. Actually the compiler doesn't even let you remove objects from a list while iterating it in a `foreach`. But you can easily do that in a `for`-loop.

Let's say I have an Interface `IEnemy` which has a method that returns a `boolean`.

```
public interface IEnemy
{
 bool IsDead();
}
```

In some other class I have a list `List<IEnemy> enemies;`. Now this is how I would remove all enemies from the list which are dead:

```
public void RemoveDead(List<IEnemy> enemies) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count;i++ )
            {
                if(enemies[i].IsDead() == true)
                {
                    enemies.Remove(enemies[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

But as this cheat sheet stated this is bad practice. So how would one do that correctly? I gues this could be done with some LINQ-statement, Lambda expression? And is this even true that this should not be done in `for`-loops?

Comment: You cannot remove from the list while enumerating over it in `foreach` loop but it's completely fine to do it in `for` loop.

Comment: This for loop will not work. It's possible it will skip items. When an item is removed, the items ahead of it will be moved down one spot. That means the item at i+1 will move to i. So, i++ will cause that item to be skipped. A simple fix for this is to enumerate from the end of the list and do i--.

Comment: Does the cheat sheet tell you *why* that particular code is bad? If not, then perhaps you should find a different cheat sheet. Make no mistake, it is bad, but it should tell you why. (see @Dennis_E remark for why)

Comment: Although I do not understand why the question has been downvoted two times, I have to admit that I got the whole thing wrong. Now that I got the link again and looked up why one should not do that I realized that the sheet suggests not to modify the loop-variables. Which in a foreach still would be the objects I am iterating on but in a for-loop that would be i (in most cases).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wdka673a(v=vs.100).aspx) method

```
enemies.RemoveAll(enemy => enemy.IsDead());
```